# Assembly (AT&T) read memory to register?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, zero-extension

In assembly I am trying to add 32 bits from memory to 64 registers, this will load 64 bits:

```
add arr(,%rax,4), %rbx
```

So I tried:

```
add arr(,%rax,4), %rbx
```

which didn't work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Note: I am reading unsigned numbers

Comment: You need to zero extend into a separate register first then add that. E.g. `movl arr(,%rax,4), %edx; add %rdx, %rbx` (remember that 32 bit register writes automatically zero extend).

Comment: Are the two examples different in any way? How?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot perform the operation directly, but in two steps: First you need to zero extend your value into an additional register, and then you can use it for the addition.

Something like this should do the work:

```
    movl arr(,%rax,4), %edx
    add %rdx, %rbx
```